# Change only part of url all the time

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change the way my url displays on the bar all the time.

For example from

```
www.mydomain.com/xxx/about
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/yyy/about
```

But not only for the about section, but even for home, contact etc.

I've tried reading other answers and applying them to my needs using htaccess but they didn't work.

Here's what I tried

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^xxx/(.*) yyy/$1
```

Comment: Your rule looks like it should work. It rewrites `/xxx/foobar` to `/yyy/foobar` without changing the url in browser address bar. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: When I write the new url `yyy/foobar` it just redirects me to the `xxx/foobar` , it doesn't show a different url

Comment: Use `R` flag for url redirection. 
`RewriteRule ^xxx/(.*) yyy/$1 [R,L]`

Comment: It still doesn't work.